# etherwallet.online - Scam or no?

Tags: ether, wallets

I signed up for a wallet [here](https://etherwallet.online/index.php) 3 days ago, and sent 1 Ether to it. [Etherescan](http://www.etherscan.io) showed the transaction as complete, and a trace of my wallet address on the same site showed an amount of 1 Ether, but my wallet on [EtherWallet](http://etherwallet.online) showed 0 Ether.

It's now 3 days later and my wallet still shows 0 Ether. I have tried contacting [EtherWallet](http://etherwallet.io) using their support contact form, their email address, and even their phone number, which goes to a completely different company.

Strangely, on [EthereScan](http://etherscan.io), there seems to be another transaction on my wallet address showing that the deposited ethereum was moved to another address 1 day after I deposited it.

Can anyone help me out with this please?

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/468/should-i-use-any-ethereum-wallet-listed-on-your-search-engine-or-advertisments

Comment: It seems likely that you will never get that ether back. See the link provided by @RichardHorrocks for more-trusted wallets

Comment: Sorry to hear about your trouble. Perhaps in the sending an finney or a sabo might be a better idea than playing around with a full ether. Just a suggestion, and again, sorry for your trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the [MetaMask](https://metamask.io/) plug-in installed in my Chrome browser.

If I click on the link in your question<sup>1</sup>, MetaMask kicks in and automatically redirects me to the MetaMask phishing warning page: https://metamask.io/phishing.html

This means the site tested positive in their [Ethereum Phishing Detector](https://github.com/metamask/eth-phishing-detect). So unfortunately it's unlikely you'll see your funds again, I'm afraid.

See [here](https://github.com/MetaMask/eth-phishing-detect/blob/master/src/config.json) for their white- and black-list of domains. Stay away from anything on the black-list.

(<sup>1</sup>I'm inside a VM, I wouldn't normally recommend clicking on links you consider insecure/dodgy.)

Comment: Richard - Thanks for checking it out, looks like I got screwed :(

Comment: Hi, I'm a maintainer of the blacklist MetaMask is referencing - you can get more information about a site here: https://etherscamdb.info/scam/102/

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news Rick :-( Be careful out there. That plug-in is pretty good for future, though I know it's a bit late now.

Comment: Annoying - I have metamask installed on my other computer, but couldn't remember the key to add it to this one. Lesson learned I guess. Is there anywhere I can share the address to alert others?

Comment: *"I have metamask installed on my other computer, but couldn't remember the key to add it to this one"* - you just need the extension on your browser, you don't need to log into it for it to do the blacklist check btw